# Modify Shopify.addItem function definition to add restriction for add to cart request

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, shopify, overriding

Shopify offers a `Shopify` JavaScript object which looks like below in the picture
[image: Shopify Object on a Shopify store]
You can also see it for yourself by visiting this link of a  [Shopify store](http://bit2byt.myshopify.com). Open console and type `Shopify`.
Now, I have the need to modify the behavior of `addItem` function. We can override a function in JavaScript, but when I access `Shopify.addItem` later in any file it gives `undefined`. To be clear, `Shopify` object along with all function definitions is defined inside `theme.js` file and my snippet in which I am trying to override is added below this file for sure. I am able to access `Shopify` object but I am unable to access this function therefore unable to override it. Below is the definition of Shopify.addItem.

```js
Shopify.addItem = function(variant_id, quantity, callback) {
  var quantity = quantity || 1;
  var params = {
    type: 'POST',
    url: '/cart/add.js',
    data: 'quantity=' + quantity + '&id=' + variant_id,
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(line_item) {
      console.log('in add Item');
      if ((typeof callback) === 'function') {
        callback(line_item);
      }
      else {
        Shopify.onItemAdded(line_item);
      }
    },
    error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus) {
      Shopify.onError(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus);
    }
  };
  jQuery.ajax(params);
};
```

Here is my code trying to override it.

```js
  (function(){
    var originalAddItem = Shopify.addItem;
    Shopify.addItem = function(){

      console.log('in overriden function');
      return originalAddItem.apply(this,arguments);

    };
  })();
```

But this never gets executed and when I `console.log(Shopify)` it still contains the original definition of function. Any ideas how to achieve it?

Answer (score 0):

Your theme is loading the Javascript that provides the Shopify object. You can verify this easily by examining your theme and the way your Javascript is loaded. There are two ways of achieving this. One is to grab a copy of the Shopify issued JS and load it in your theme as an asset (asset_url filter), while the second is to simply load the CDN version from Shopify mothership (shopify_asset_url filter).

Example: look for

```
  {{ 'shopify_common.js' | shopify_asset_url | script_tag }}
```

vs

```
  {{ 'shopify_common_custom.js' | asset_url | script_tag }}
```

If you grab your own copy and load it as an asset from your shop, you can certainly override that object and the functionality. I have been doing that since 2006, so can you. You could also do away with the Shopify code and use Gavin's CartJS which is the same API but nicer. Your choice.

Comment: Hi David... I have tried to inspect 'shopify_common.js' but I think its not providing the Shopify object. I see `if ((typeof Shopify) === 'undefined') { Shopify = {}; }` inside `theme.js.liquid` file.

Comment: Moreover, `  {% if template.directory == 'customers' %}
    {{ 'shopify_common.js' | shopify_asset_url | script_tag }}
    {{ 'customer_area.js'  | shopify_asset_url | script_tag }}
  {% endif %}` , 'shopify_common.js' is inside condition.. I am on development store for now.

Comment: As I mentioned, grab your own copies of that code, and then you can safely override anything you want.